# custom preference layout and theme consistent with the default one?

Tags: android, settings, preference

I am new to android development. I am working on settings preference (seekbar preference to be specific), I know how to customize a preference's layout, but the theme, layout or style are not consistent with the default one, so my question is, how can I make it (text size, padding, margin etc.) the same as the default one? for instance, the sound setting in system setting [the sound setting seekbar preference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Frb.png)

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't just using a [SeekbarPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/SeekBarPreference.html)?

Comment: i am not using support v7.preference library, and the app i am developing implement a range seekbar (dual thumb seekbar), the company asks for a specific layout as well. Even if i am using this library it wont satisfy the requirements, and I am not curious about only the seekbar but also custom preference in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I make it (text size, padding, margin etc.) the same as the default one?

Base yours on one of the layouts used for an existing preference type. Those layouts can be found in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/.../data/res/layout/, where`$ANDROID_SDK`is wherever you have installed the Android SDK and`...`is some platform version (e.g.,`android-26`for Android 8.0). The layout resources prefixed with`preference_`pertain to preferences, and`preference_widget_seekbar_material.xml` is the Material Design one.

If you were using `appcompat-v7`, you would perform a similar operation, poking through that library's code, which is part of [this AOSP repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/).

Comment: Thx! so for different sdk the layout might be different?

Comment: @lxinghe: It usually varies by theme. `Theme.Holo`-based preferences will look a bit different than will `Theme.Material`-based preferences.